# NSCFNumber unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, xcode, read-write, unrecognized-selector

i want to send data between views, but i get an error: **unrecognized selector**....

and the in the debugger, the variable **mystring** is a NSCFNumber ("at this time") instead of NSString...

> allergy_appAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface allergy_appAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
    NSMutableArray  *result_array;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (copy , readwrite) NSMutableArray *result_array;

@end
```

> viewcontroller.m

```
        allergy_appAppDelegate *dataCenter = (allergy_appAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        dataCenter.result_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:Parser_result];
```

> result.m

```
   allergy_appAppDelegate *dataCenter = (allergy_appAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   show_user_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: dataCenter.result_array]

for (NSString *mystring in show_user_array) {        
    textView.text = [[textView text] stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    textView.text = [[textView text] stringByAppendingString:mystring];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables should be camel-cased, not have _.  I.e. `result_array` should be `resultArray`.  Classes start with capital letters.

Are you sure your result array is full of instances of `NSString` or `NSNumber` (or whatever you need)?

Given that you are leaking the array here...

```
    dataCenter.result_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:Parser_result];
```

... it is unlikely that this is an over-release problem.  Note also that `copy` with `NSMutableArray` won't do what you want (the compiler should flag it, but doesn't).  `-copy` always returns an immutable copy of an instance of a class cluster.

Comment: the array is full of instances of NSString... i tried read-write property but i had no success..